# show small loader icon while loading an wide image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this script to load some images after page loading is complete I want to know how I can show a loader text or small gif icon while images are loading.

```
$(function () {
        $(".product-image-holder").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("alt"));
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show / hide the loader yourself.

**For each image a different loader**

```
$(".product-image-holder").each(function () {
        $(this).bind("load", function(){
            // Hide loader code here for this image
        });
        // Show loader code here for this image
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("alt"));
    });
```

**1 loader for all images**

```
// Show your loader here
var totalToLoad = $(".product-image-holder").length;
var loaded = 0;
$(".product-image-holder").each(function () {
        $(this).bind("load", function(){
            loaded++;
            if(loaded == totalToLoad)
            {
                // Hide your loader here
            }
        });
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("alt"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Straight forward

**Note -** ( Answer will be valid if `<img class='.product-image-holder' />` is having some parent HTML tag say `<div><img class='.product-image-holder' /></div>` )

```
$(function () {
        $(".product-image-holder").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr("alt"));
            $(this).parent().load("http://example.com/any-other-image.jpg");
        });
});
```